# How do I produce an uneven offset /solidify modify on a cube?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to create an offset that is wider on one side than the other and i have been using the solidify modify tool, however this creates an even offset. I am relatively new to blender and so any information would be useful. Thanks.

Comment: Solidify modifier can use a vertex group as parameter. So the offset will depend on the vertex weight in the group. Could you add a picture of what you want to obtain?

Answer (score 3):

If you are solidifying through the *Solidify* modifier you can use a vertex group to control thickness.

Create a vertex group and add all desired vertex to it, set solidify thickness to a known value so multiplying by a factor is easy, like say $1.0$ units, or $0.1$ Units.

This value will be multiplied by the Vertex Weight set for that vertex. Now adjust thickness on a per vertex basis adjusting vertex weight.

With with weight paint, *[Vertex Weight Proximity](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153177/worms-crawling-under-skin/153181?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C34.3075#153181)* modifier, or manually.

[image]