# Deform mesh based on proximity

Tags: mesh

I have a scene where I want my character to sit on a sofa. To make it look better, I want the sofa to deform like it would in reality. What is the best way to do this?

- I can try and sculpt shapekeys, but this is a real pain if I have an animated scene.
- I know there is a Cast Modifier which does exactly that. But the Cast modifier cannot be applied
  to geometry. This only works for cubes and spheres.
- I can also use Soft Body, but it takes too much time to simulate that. I'm looking for a more simple solution.
- There is also the possibility to archieve this using dynamic paint, but isn't there an easier way?

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? With the new geometry nodes and proximity attribute, I'm sure there is someone who knows ;)

Thanks!

Comment: An alternative way would be to use a lattice on the sofa, which is sculpted to deform it like someone sits on it. Than you would need to link the horizontal position to the character using constraints and the deformation amount to the characters hips Z position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not physics but you could do it with shape keys: Create a basis shapekey, then a second one, keep the second one selected, sculpt (in *Object* mode with the *Value* at 1) or model (in *Edit* mode) the sofa in order to create the shape it is supposed to get when the character sits down, then keyframe the shapekey's *Value*:

[image]

Comment: Man I really appreciate the quick response! I once used this method too. But the scene I am trying to create is a character sitting down, turning and laying on his back looking up. I can create multiple shapekeys and animate that using this method, but that takes too much time. Using soft body would be much easier for me. But i'm trying to avoid that because baking around 1200 frames takes time and lots of space :P. What I am looking for is a Cast  modifier, but for geometry objects. Thanks!

Comment: With bones? Mesh Deform? Vertex Weight Proximity? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153177/worms-crawling-under-skin ... I guess it also depends on the style

Comment: It's kinda cartoony, so it doesn't have to be that complex or convincing. But using bones needs to be animated. The downside is that if I have to adjust the characters animation, I also need to adjust the entire sofa animation. I'm beeing lazy I know XD. My best bet is to use soft body, unless I know how to use the proximity in the new geometry node system. I couldnt find a tutorial on this.

Comment: YES!!!! That's it!!! Thank you so much!!! I couldnt find this!!

Comment: well, you need to thank Duarte  ^^  for a cartoon I would use bones or Mesh Deform I guess, but maybe you'll get what you want with Vertex Weight Proximity