# Drop rigid body onto soft body

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, collision, soft-body

I just [asked this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230700/drop-rigid-body-onto-soft-body-and-leave-an-impression) and it was closed as being a duplicate of [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230543/using-an-object-to-deform-another-object-like-punching-a-pillow-whats-the-bes).  However I cannot get the solution from that previous question to work (explain in more detail below).  Also I don't feel that the slight impression the cube leaves on the pillow in that answer is the same effect I am looking for in this question (more closely molded)

To recap:

**What I want to do**

I want to drop this object onto this cube and leave an impression.  Almost as if the top object was metal and the bottom object was silly putty.  I am actually going to be 3d printing both objects and I want the cube to "hold" the top object.  I realize I could potentially do that with booleans but due to some problems with underhangs, etc...  I think this might be a better solution. (Compared to the previous question this was supposedly a duplicate of, the impression would be a pretty close "mold" of the top object, not just like an indent on a trampoline). Also once I got going down this path I wanted to figure it out for curiousity sake.

[image]

**What I've tried**

I selected the top object and clicked "rigid body" and I selected the bottom object and hit "soft body" and then pressed play.  The top object "drops" like I want it to, but it passes right through the bottom object.

[Per this answer on here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96744/is-there-a-way-to-make-rigid-body-interact-with-softbody-physics) I tried a few things.

1. Made sure the rigid body had collision enabled--still passed through.
2. For the heck of it made sure soft body also had collision turned on-- still passed through.  I then turned that back off since it didn't seem to do anything.
3. Added rigid body physics to the soft body--- they both fall when I do that
4. Changed the rigid body physics on the cube to be passive and animated, changed shape to mesh and enabled deforming(per that answer)-- progress.  The top object collides with the cube after passing through it a little bit, but it doesn't affect the "surface" of the cube at all.   I.e. it does this and stays put:
   [image]
5. Under the assumption that maybe it doesn't distort the top of the cube enough because its too simple of a cube, I subdivided it a bunch.  No change.
6. I tried swapping the "soft body" with "cloth" to see if that would behave differently and it didn't.  They both fall but the top rigid body catches up and kinda gets about the same amount through.

**What I tried from that 'duplicate' question**

It was suggested that [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230543/using-an-object-to-deform-another-object-like-punching-a-pillow-whats-the-bes) was a duplicate, so I tried it.

- I subdivided the cube etc..  like they said
- Picked the vertices and made a vertex group
- added cloth physics, inserted my vertex group as a pin group and checked the pressure with the value of 5 (the only thing I didn't do on that step was uncheck goal, where is that? I'm in blender 2.93)
- Made sure my top object had collision (with and without rigid body as well, tried both)
- This is what happens to my cube when I hit play
  [image]

Any ideas?  Again, I'd love the bottom cube to kinda "squish" around the top rigid object that's falling into it.  Thank you!

**Alternate approach I'd be ok with**

So to recap, I'd like the cube to be molded pretty tightly around the object, almost like a boolean.  Imagine squishing the top object into silly putty.   The only reason I didn't use a boolean is because if there are over/underhangs I don't want the cube to wrap around it and 'catch' the edge.  If its easier to drop the cube onto the rigid object instead of rigid onto cube then I'm all for it.

Comment: Can u please share your blend file for your 2nd try so I will check it out?

Comment: @Chris  Here you go:  https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnsEucAtFS_Slok7pl-vVfZ6ayQmtQ?e=ofyPEr