# How can I make one object affect the z-axis transformation of another object?

Tags: animation, transforms, drivers

(Sorry for the confusing title, I didn't know how to explain this)

I have a sphere and a lot of tiles in a scene:

[image]

I want all the tiles to move up and down when the sphere gets close to them:

[image]

I tried to use a driver on the tiles, but instead of all the specific tiles moving when the sphere got close to them, they just mirrored the location of the sphere:

[image]

I'm not sure if drivers are the best way to do this, if it isn't, please let me know how I can do this!

Thanks
Daniel

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153177/worms-crawling-under-skin/153181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were very close, If you added driver for the tiles z location to copy it from the sphere, you need to create an "fallof" effect - Open driver editor add input variable, change it's type to distance, in the expression now you can divide position value by distance value.
To make the fallof effect stronger/weaker divide/multiply the distance by some constant value.
Keep in mind that when the distance will be between 0:1 then you will divide position by a fraction - which means it will actually exaturate it, so to keep it on a safe side, you can simply add 1 to your distance/strength_factor.

[image]

Comment: Since he has no distance in his driver, to provide a good answer it would be best to tell him how to get the distance.