# is it possible to make this in blender

Tags: modeling, animation, physics, fluid-simulation

I can't seem to find any videos explaining how to make something like this. All I find are videos on how to make fluid flow from something. Basically basic fluid stuff. But I'm wondering if this effect can be done in blender at all and if so please send me a video link. I don't know what it's properly called, so I'm not sure how to look it up.

[image]

Comment: It can certainly be done, but probably not with a fluid sim. I'm thinking along the lines of vector displacement or geo nodes.

Comment: Reminds me of this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/153181/33589

Comment: In physics, that would be an example of field based attraction, like the attraction of iron filings to a magnet, so I'd look for things like [magnetic attraction](https://blenderartists.org/t/magnetic-attraction/546294) in my search

Comment: Can you give this question a proper title? Titles like "how to model this?" or "is it possible to make this in blender?" are really meaningless. What is "*this*"? It's as bad as this answer: "Yes, it is possible."  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKTOU.gif  ;-)