# Human face moving under wall

Tags: mesh, modifiers, displacement, surface-deform

Good day everyone, I am trying to create an animation of a person's face moving under a wall. something similar to the picture attached
[image: result I'm trying to achieve].

I have tried the same method here [Worms crawling under skin](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153177/worms-crawling-under-skin/153181#153181) . But it doesn't come out properly

Please is it possible to do achieve the result without shapekey?

Comment: Could use shrinkwrap, geometry nodes, deform/hooks or shapekeys as you mentioned which could actually be a nice solution. Up to your artistic choice which tools to use.

Comment: I've answered with the Lattice solution but you don't give any detail about what's the animation supposed to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a *Lattice* modifier and move the vertices of your lattice cage in order to model the face on the wall. You don't give any detail about the kind of animation you want but you can vary the *Strength* of the modifier so that the face seems to emerge.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much