# How do I get a cloth plane to "go back" to its original shape after being disrupted?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, collision

(I'm still learning Blender as I am quite new to it).

I am trying to make a model of Space time curvature, it consists of a wireframe plane (cloth) and multiple Spheres (with collisions). The component of this is to get the Sphere to orbit a larger objects whilst disrupting the plane (creating curvature). Currently, when the sphere disrupts the plane, it leaves it disrupted and the plane does not return to its original shape. Is there a way to get the plane to return to its original shape after getting disrupted?

[image: example of the cloth disruption]

Comment: How have you done this? Using dynamic paint?

Comment: you could use another method like for example the Warp modifier, or the Lattice modifier?

Comment: I have made this simply adding spheres and planes.  If I were to use warp or lattice modifier should I use it on the plane or the sphere? Thanks

Comment: you'd need to use it on the plane, see this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153177/worms-crawling-under-skin

Answer (score 2):

what about using geometry nodes? i am not sure, whether this is the effect you are looking for...but with this node setup:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

It is a pretty basic setup using the geometry proximity node to just offset to z value of the grid. The map range node determines the shape, height and width of the grid deforming.