Blender distance map?
Does blender have something like a distance map? Where you can use other objects to influence an object only by using its material/distance map?
https://support.chaos.com/hc/en-us/articles/4528348048017-Corona-Distance-Map-3ds-Max
https://fstormrender.com/manual/fstorm-distance/

hello, I'm not sure this is what you want but maybe check Duarte's answer here, is it what you want? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153177/worms-crawling-under-skin/153179#153179

Geometry nodes has a "Distance to Nearest Surface" node that can provide you with this data. Then you can store that as an attribute and use it in the shader editor with an Attribute node.

Hey, can you make a quick screenshot?
